# how to draw graph having single node in networkx?

Tags: python-2.7, networkx

```
import networkx as nx  
G=nx.Graph()  
G.add_node("spam")  
nx.draw_networkx(G, node_size = 2000, node_color = "white", pos=nx.spring_layout(G))
```

I tried this but it is showing `error` like

```
return {G.nodes()[0]: center}  

TypeError: 'dictionary-keyiterator' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: What version of networkx are you using?  The code you've given works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

use nx.random_layout(G) method in stead of nx.spring_layout(G)

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug, now reported https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues/2079

A workaround is to explicitly put the position of the single node into the position dictionary.
For example

```
import networkx as nx
G=nx.Graph()
G.add_node("spam")
nx.draw_networkx(G, node_size = 2000, node_color = "white", pos={'spam':(1,1)})
```